# What does the number accompanying the line number in StackTrace mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving an error in the hosted app and am trying to understand why the error is happening.

For this i look at the stack trace on the error page, which is as follows:

[

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MBANinja.demo.DemoTestPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +696
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

Now I always thought the number accompanying the method call is the line number where the error was encountered. But that particular page has code (DemoTestPage)e only till 220's. So wht does +696 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get line numbers only if debug information (the pdb file) is available, otherwise you get an offset in the current method.